# Reboot / Shutdown with Gnome 3 on Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, shutdown, reboot

I have a problem with `Gnome 3` on my Debian 7 install.

I can't use Desktop button to reboot or shutdown because my screen freezes.

I tried in command line `reboot -f` as admin and it's working but it's a bit boring to open the terminal each time I want to reboot my computer.

I didn't find any command to shutdown completely my computer.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does running `/sbin/poweroff` work for you (being run from a terminal emulator window, with the admin credentials)?

Comment: Also you might consider upgrading your system to the testing distribution (Debian 8, Jessie) -- or installing it afresh -- because it incorporates newer versions of many pieces of software, including the kernel, which might fix your problem. Jessie is "frozen" now which means that there will be no new versions of software appear in it before the release, only bugfixes, so the probability of breakage due to package updates should be almost zero.

Comment: I mean, if it's a bug in GNOME 3 or some other component as shipped in Debian 7, it's a bit too late to report because the new release is approaching and I'm not sure anyone will be motivated to work on the fix for a distribution which is nearing its end of life.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. `/sbin/poweroff` isn't working. I made my whole PXE installation with `Wheezy` then I can't change Debian version now. I must fix these bugs.